# Router's ftp server isn't listing large files

Tags: router, ftp, lan

I have a ZTE modem, with USB file sharing enabled through FTP for WLAN. It works fine for streaming, downloading softwares and other transfers but within a size range of 2Gb. The software setups and movies with the size greater than 2GBs just doesn't list in directories.
Well I don't know much about troubleshooting this, but I have tried windows cmd ftp tool and `ls`command there shows the heavy files but still I'm unable to `get` them.

Well if ftp doesn't have any file size limitations problem then there might be a problem with router, like maybe I'm missing some configuration or maybe it has something to do with the storage drives.

Comment: It seems like some software is 32-bit, because of the file size limit. Have you tried updating, and ensuring that 64-bit software is installed?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Router's software? Well the modem is updated with the latest firmware but if it's about explorer, then I have tried x64 softwares. In windows I usually use file explorer, and Filezilla.

Comment: Does your router support SFTP?  If you can `ssh` into it, it probably does.  Filezilla and WinSCP are two example SFTP clients.  See if that works.

Comment: @LawrenceC It has an option of ssh, and I checked it but it doesn't work when I use command in console or smartftp (software). It just stuck on loading screen and cmd deny the access. Well I also searched it around, andI think it might be related to router's limitations. Most routers support hard drives upto 2TB, and maybe they also have per file size limitation. At first I thought it might have something to do with cluster size of volume formatting, but I checked that too and it doesn't work. Router is just ignoring files greater than 2GB, and if it's not the problem with ftp then it's router